# Not able to see the page Create your Account

Tags: login

Accessing the `../admin` page, it shows me the login page directly instead of create your account page. I don't have any account for Craft so I'll definitely need to create an account of mine in Craft but not able to find the Create Your Account page.

Answer (score 1):

You or the person who setup your system created an user account. See step 5 in the installation documentation (http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/installing). Therefore there should be an account and you could try to reset the password.

If you have access to the DB directly you could get or set the email/username associated to that account. Another option would be to start with a fresh installation.